# Mapped networks drive in C# on Windows 7 with GetDrives does not appears

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7-x64, network-drive

I have on one side a client application (running with C# 4.0 on Windows 7 64), which needs to see which remote drives from the server side are mapped.

On the other side, a server application is running (using Windows 2008 R2) under a service account called "Mydomain\MyApplicationSRV". 
When I'm logged on the server side, the remote drives are mapped, and are ready. 
When I'm asking to the server thru my client to send me back which network drives are mapped, the server does not send back any remote drives (using the DriveInfos.GetDrives() code) but sends back the "local" drives.

I read a lot of subjects about this "issue", and try several things :

1. [EnableLinkedConnections on registry](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) : failed.
2. [net use with persistent](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019185) : failed
3. and a lot of discussions on stackoverflow (but most are with IIS issues, that is not my case).

Any Ideas?

Comment: Depending on mapped drives is never not a mistake.  Windows makes sure that different user accounts and different sessions don't step on each other's mappings.  You might get the user account right, pretty questionable itself, you probably didn't get the session right.  Nor can you, services run in isolated session 0.  Don't use mapped drives.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean by "services run in isolated session0". Please Can you explain ?